# Laravel show view with use relations, join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem because i make big relation through using join in laravel and I don't know how to use data in this query.

My model:

```
public function getrelationquery(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Modtwo',"modtwoforeign","id")
            ->join('Pmodel',"Pmodel.id",'=','Modtwo.pp')
            ->join("Cpmodel","Cpmodel.pr","=","Modtwo.id")
            ->join("Ccmodel","Ccmodel.id","=","Cpmodel.cc");

    }
```

My controller:

```
            $q = Mymodel::find($id)->with(array('getrelationquery'=>function($query) use ($id_other){
                $query->where('secvar',$id_other);//id_other is the secound variable
            }))->get();

            $pd = $q;
            print_r($pd);
            return view('view/displaydata', compact('pd'));
```

When I use print_r I see all the data but I don't know how display it on view. I need to display data from Ccmodel and Pmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pd` is collection of your object, so you can use foreach to extract your object

```
@foreach($pd as $data)
    {{ $data->column_name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: so but I have to use the foreach several times to get the data they want, are there any other ways? Or, if you can get a table for example. @foreach($pd->Ccmodel as $data) ?

Comment: yes you can call it, just make sure you add belongsTo function in MyModel to CpModel and CcModel

Comment: Just on that exchange hasMany to belongsto?